# Laravel Queue with Amazon SQS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, queue, amazon-sqs

Hi I am new in laravel 4, getting trouble while configuring AWS SQS in my local machine. I need to push some jobs in the AWS queue and execute them sequentially.

I have set the required values in **app/config/queue.php**

```
 'sqs' => array(
     'driver' => 'sqs',
     'key'    => 'XXXXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
      'queue'  => 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXX/myqueue',
      'region' => 'us-west-2',
   ),
```

and have also override the queue value in **app/config/local/queue.php**

```
$queue = include __DIR__ . "/../queue.php";
$queue['connections']['sqs']['queue'] = 'https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXX/mylocalqueue';
return $queue;
```

Also I have changed updated the **bootstrap/start.php** to set the environment as local

```
<?php
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
'local' => array('my-machine-name'),
));
```

I have pushed the jobs in queue in the controller function as following

```
public function pus_aws($data){
    $queue = $this->app['queue'];
    $queue->push('\ControllerName@ActionName', array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));

    return true;
}
```

But it is not working. Can anybody please help me to push and run the queued jobs?

Comment: I am facing a same issue please let me know if you got any breakthrough.. Thanks

Comment: What sort of errors are you seeing?

Comment: I did find any related error in Apache error_log file

Comment: @Prosenjit where can you get the public key of amazon?

Answer (score 8):

Are you listening on the queue?

```
php artisan queue:listen --env=your_environment
```

http://laravel.com/docs/queues#running-the-queue-listener

For Production-Setup, you should use supervisor as stated in the Laravel Docs.

See this for a tutorial (uses beanstalkd, but is the same for sqs, only that you do not have to install beanstalkd)
http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4

Comment: thanks for your help
php artisan queue:listen works for me, but the listener exits after some time. do I need to setup a demon or cron for 
1)  php artisan queue:listen
2) php artisan queue:work

Thanks

Comment: Right, as stated in the answer, see this link [http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4](http://fideloper.com/ubuntu-beanstalkd-and-laravel4) to set up **supervisor**. This restarts the queue:listen if it exits.